# Are there delimiter bytes for UTF8 characters?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

If I have a byte array that contains UTF8 content, how would I go about parsing it? Are there delimiter bytes that I can split off to get each character?

Comment: Be careful of malformed input, make sure your code doesn't do something bad like a buffer overflow if a sequence comes in over 4 bytes for example.

Comment: Once you've done the necessary bit-picking, you end up with a bunch of characters each from 1 to 4 bytes long; what are you going to do with that? Why don't you just decode it and work on the resultant Unicode characters?

Comment: @JohnMachin in my case, the "bunch of characters" is too large to be processed in one go, and my code searches for a safe byte offset to slice the data into smaller chunks that can be worked with individually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look here...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

If you're looking to identify the boundary between characters, what you need is in the table in "Description".

The only way to get a high bit zero is the ASCII subset 0..127, encoded in a single byte. All the non-ASCII codepoints have 2nd byte onwards with "10" in the highest two bits. The leading byte of a codepoint never has that - it's high bits indicate the number of bytes, but there's some redundancy - you could equally watch for the next byte that doesn't have the "10" to indicate the next codepoint.

```
0xxxxxxx : ASCII
10xxxxxx : 2nd, 3rd or 4th byte of code
11xxxxxx : 1st byte of code, further high bits indicating number of bytes
```

A codepoint in unicode isn't necessarily the same as a character. There are modifier codepoints (such as accents), for instance.

Comment: What about emoji variation sequences? For example if the character `U+1F469` (in binary `11110000 10011111 10010001 10101001`) is on it's own, you get the "woman" emoji. However if it's followed by `U+1F3FD` (in binary `11110000 10011111 10001111 10111101`) then it will be a woman with brown skin. How can you safely detect this boundary to avoid breaking utf-8 bytes in between the two? Both codepoints are valid on their own (the latter is rendered as a brown square on OS X), but users would not expect them to be split up.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - you're thinking at the wrong layer. UTF-8 doesn't define or care about how sequences of Unicode codepoints relate to each other. First, you translate UTF-8 (or other encodings) to a Unicode codepoint stream, then you interpret that. I don't know Unicode-specific details, but a general approach to the problem of handling modifier codepoints is the same as recognizing keywords and other tokens in a programming language tokenizer. There's probably a better Unicode-specific way but I don't know and in any case, you should ask a separate question.

Comment: I'm trying to identify "the boundary between characters", where a "character" is a single glyph being drawn to the screen, which is exactly the question you're answering as far as I can see. I'm splitting a large (potentially gigabytes) amount of utf-8 data into smaller pieces (tens of bytes in length) that are drawn to the screen individually, and this will break silently if the bytes are separated the way you suggest in your answer.

Comment: @Abhi - You're right that this answer doesn't solve your problem - it answers the question OP asked. My answer is about which bytes form a particular Unicode codepoint. As I said, which Unicode codepoints form a particular glyph is a different thing which UTF-8 doesn't define. Unicode is a different layer to the UTF-8, UTF-16 etc encodings. I still don't know the answer to your problem beyond what I already said. Writing comments on a 6 year old answer means the people who could answer your question will never see it. And BTW I am not, and never was, a Unicode expert.

Answer (score 0):

Bytes that have the first bit set to 0 are normal ASCII characters. Bytes that have their first bit set to 1 are part of a UTF-8 character.

The first byte in every UTF-8 character has its second bit set to 1, so that the byte has the most significant bits `11`. Each following byte that belongs to the same UTF-8 character starts with `10` instead.

The first byte of each UTF-8 character additionally indicates how many of the following bytes belong to the character, depending on the number of bits that are set to 1 in the most significant bits of that byte.

For more details, see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for UTF-8.

Comment: "UTF-8 character" is a misnomer.  You seem to be referring to a sequence of two to four bytes which represents a non-ASCII character.  When it comes to understanding Unicode, I believe getting the vocabulary right is half the battle.